Simple Child to Parent SOQL Query not working
I thought these Nonprofit Cloud objects would behave just like Contacts and Accounts. Are these not Standard Objects?
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM BenefitDisbursements) FROM InteractionSummary

Error:
Didn't understand relationship 'BenefitDisbursements' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
Please advise

The child relationship name (which is the thing you need to use in the subquery) isn't always obvious. The Salesforce workbench can probably help, but getting it through Apex (which you could run as anon apex) is probably quicker/more straightforward.

InteractionSummary is child to benefit assignment, so you need to use dotted notation to refer to the parent fields.  Search the nonprofit cloud data model and standard object help pages for details in the relationships
